# Append Text to a complete html string

Tags: c#, html, string, text, append

I have a string that's a full HTML document text - it ends with the closing html tag. I need to append text and newline to this htmlText. Sometimes I need to insert a line before the htmlText, sometimes after.

Is it correct to just do stringText + "'<'br/>" + htmlText + "'<'br/>" + moreStringText?

So far, what I tested looked right, but I'm not sure what the correct way to handle this is?

Thanks,

Mike T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution - using DevEx RichEditDocumentServer interface, I'm using the SubDocument InsertHtml and InsertText methods, and it's working great!

Answer (score 1):

Any text that you want to be rendered as part of a webpage needs to be placed inside the `<html>` and `</html>` tags for it to be valid.

Passing the following

```
<!doctype html><head><title>Html Page</title></head></html>

My text here
```

to the [W3 HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea) generates the following error:

```
Error: Non-space character in page trailer.
From line 3, column 1; to line 3, column 11
></html>↩↩My text here
```

Also, as [slnit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6175288/slnit) says, you should use a [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder) instead of using String concatenation.

What text are you wanting to add to the beginning or end of the HTML page?

Comment: Correct about StringBuilder - I just wanted to show the question in the simplest way.

I have an html field and I need to concatenate another field - not html to it. It's always different text. But I'm going to need to add to the end/beginning of the html with a new line separator.

Comment: @MikeTurner do you have some examples? I'm struggling to understand why you need to do this :)

Comment: no example - its a business requirement.

i save some text in html together with all its formatting (color, bold etc) and I need to append with other text that in plain text (no formatting) to have a complete document that will have formatting on top and no special formatting on bottom.

Comment: Simplest case for you I think would be to strip the closing `<html>` tag from your htmlText string, append your new string on the end and then add a new closing tag afterwards. The new string should really be wrapped in a `<p>` or `<div>` tag though

Comment: It's a drop more complicated, I need a better solution. Html can be formatted in many ways, I can have doctype in the beginning sometimes, its complicated.

Comment: You should probably ask a separate question for this, but without some example code we can't help you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can use SringBuilder class.

string body = " some text";

```
        StringBuilder buildHtml = new StringBuilder();
        buildHtml.Append("<HTML>");
        buildHtml.AppendLine(body);
        buildHtml.Append("</HTML>");
        string sHtml = buildHtml.ToString();
```

Comment: Sorry - this is not my question. I am not asking how to put together an html string. Like I said, I have a string that's full html text and I need to concatenate with other plain non-html strings. How do I do that? Can I just append them all, or do the plain text strings need to be inserted inside the proper html tags which is much more complex?

Comment: string html="<html>...</html>"+"another plain text";

Comment: string html="Code html";
            StringBuilder newstring = new StringBuilder();
            newstring.Append(html);
            newstring.AppendLine("PlainText");
            html = newstring.ToString();